# How do I change file extension based on the number in a file name in Python

Tags: python, filenames

I have some files stored in one main directory with `.map` extensions that are the output of a model. The filenames include the timestep of the model.

For example: `P_1_.map`, `P_2_.map` and `P_10_.map` are the output of the 1st, 2nd and 10th timestep of the model respectively.

The extension of the files has to be changed to a three-digit number that corresponds to the timestep. I need to change the `.map` extension to `.001`, `.002` and `.010`.

Finally I would like to change all the filenames to the same name, lets say "*Ptest*". In the the end the old files should be changed like this:
`P_1_.map` to  `Ptest.001`

`P_2_.map` to  `Ptest.002`

`P_10_.map` to `Ptest.010`

Does someone know how to do this in Python? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Are these files stored in subfolders or in one main directory?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I know how to change the filenames. So I started a loop:

Comment: for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.startswith("P"):
        os.rename(filename, "Ptest")

Comment: files are stored in one main directry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os

for name in os.listdir(): # look through the entire directory
    # break up the name so we can work with it
    parts = name.split('_')
    # skip non-matching files
    if len(parts) != 3: continue
    if parts[0] != 'P' or parts[2] != '.map': continue
    # figure out the new name
    newname = "Ptest.%03d" % int(parts[1])
    # do the rename
    os.rename(name, newname)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day :)